# Does Office-js has a functionality to close

Tags: office-js

I have been looking through the office-js / word api looking for a self close function that I can call, however I am unable to find anything of sorts.  Now I know that the Office-js api does not control the entire office-suite object like a VSTO.  On the other hand, if this is not possible can we expect it to become an option of future releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello by self close i guess you mean closing the task pane (not the document itself). This is not supported but please add or vote for this feature in our user voice site! 
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/163566-add-in-word?query=close